# SASS Compass Breakpoint - Including to my project error

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, breakpoints

I want to include breakpoint into my web project. I have SASS, Compass and breakpoint installed and I followed the installation guide for it, but it still dosen't seem to work correctly. Can anyone walk me through here what the errors might be.

The following code is in my config.rb file (located in project directory, main folder)

```
require 'breakpoint'

http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
```

The following code is located in style.scss (project/sass folder)

```
@import "breakpoint";

etc scss code...
```

Here is the error I get from LiveReload:

File to import not found or unreadable: compass.

Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass.
              Load path: /private/var/folders/ln/lp7d050s191cgjw1ck1gnq_h0000gn/T
        on line 4 of project/sass/style.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.

Comment: you also need to @import 'compass' if you haven't already

Comment: I did @import 'compass'; into my scss file, still dosen't work. I also added require 'compass' into the config file. Still same problem :(

Comment: I recreated the config.rb file and added the same content in it. Wired becuase now this error shows up: LoadError on line ["45"] of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- breakpoint

Comment: This is what I found on line45 on this ruby file:     if Gem::Specification.unresolved_deps.empty? then
      return gem_original_require(path)
    end

Answer (score 1):

Compass extensions tend not to work (or work well) when compiling with a GUI app (such as LiveReload or CodeKit). Instead of using LiveReload for compiling *and* reloading, just use it for reloading and run your compilation through the command line. You should also put your project under [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) version control to ensure that the gems you want to use are absolutely available. If you are having load issues, it's because your compiler can't find the gem. Compiling through the command line under Bundler control will ensure the gem is available.